# Can't see how this limit converges

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}}-1} = \frac{kT}{\hbar\omega}
$$

I plugged the limit into mathematica and got "DirectedInfinity". Tried the trick of multiplying it by 1 and see if something more elucidating would come up but nothing.

The book I got this from says that this limit is for "high T", which I interpreted as T goes to infinity. Maybe that could be the problem, nonetheless, I don't see how this limit is done.

Comment: You are correct. The limit as you have written it is $\infty$ provided $\hslash, k>0$.

Comment: Well I still would like to see how the statement in the book is true that at high T the expression reduces to kT/hw.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the right hand side goes to $\infty$ as well for $T\to\infty$. Thus, the claim of the book must really be formulated as follows:

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}}-1}=1.$$

To check this limit substitute $x = \frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}$ and write

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{e^x-1}.$$
By l'Hôpital this equals
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{e^x} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

The limit doesn't converge as given. It looks more like an asymptotic approximation as $T\to\infty$:
$$
\frac{1}{e^{\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}}-1} \sim \frac{kT}{\hbar\omega}
$$
The actual limit is
$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac1{T\left(e^{\frac{\hbar\omega}{kT}}-1\right)}=\frac{k}{\hbar\omega}
$$
which follows from applying L'Hospital to
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{ax}-1}{x}=a
$$